# Saltstack result of Orchestrate run via email

Tags: salt-stack

I was trying to find ways to get results of an Orchestrate run via email.

I have salt reactor setup right now which sends me alerts in case any job fails using SMTP. What setup should I have so that I receive an email when orchestration run starts and when it ends or in case of failure.

There is a [highstate](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/all/salt.returners.highstate_return.html) return module but that does not work with the salt orchestrate system.